# What modes is the Litany of the Saints in?

Tags: theory, modes, church-music, hymnody

I've been looking at the Litany of the Saints.  Kyrie Eleison has La as the reciting tone. But then Do is the reciting tone and the finalis. I've yet to find a mode with finalis and tenor on the same note.

The sheet music: http://www.ccwatershed.org/pdfs/63318-litany-of-the-saints-cf2o/download/

Kyrie Eleison seems to be in one of the eight modes but not the rest.  It sounds a bit like it could be in natural minor if I use my modern way of listening and thinking. It would then start on Me and end on Do.

What modes is the Litany of the Saints in?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the question is proper for this group but I think the opening part is in a transposed Sixth Mode (HypoLydian in some nomenclatures.)

Comment: I see. It could be hypolydian. That seems correct

Comment: I guessed HypoLydian as the reciting tone seems to be a minor third below the finalis. I don't know if all chants fit the 8 modes (and perigrinus).